# don't apply current options to new opened file vim

Tags: linux, vim

I frequntly open many files in vim. The problem is some files have their own options. For example:

settings for make files

```
  set noexpandtab tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4
  set list listchars=eol:¬,tab:→⠀,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:<
  hi SpecialKey ctermfg=243
  hi NonText ctermfg=243
```

settings for C files

```
  set colorcolumn=100 tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4
```

So, if I open makefile first and then `:tabe main.c` I can see invisble character that were turned on from makefile.

I understand that I can `:set nolist` but imagine if I have many other options inherit from many other files. How can I tell vim not to inherit them when I `:tabe anotherFile`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well there is `setlocal` to set this things for a buffer only.
But that does of course not work for a `.vimrc`. There you have two possibilities, autocmds or filetype plugins:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.{c} setlocal colorcolumnt=100
```

This does set the settings local to any oppened buffer of a file ending with `.c`

Or you can add the settings to a filetype-plugin. See `:h filetype-plugin` for more information on that. Basically just add the settings to a specific file. In your case most likely under `.vim/ftplugin/c.vim`